Camera is not working when I try to run my QR code project in my web browser
I have a project idea where the employee scans the QR code of the applicant that was given by the company after he submitted his application online. Whenever the employee scans the QR code the record of the applicant will automatically appear. The problem is whenever I try to run my code in Chrome browser there is no camera appearing in my browser.
I'm using XAMPP for local development with PHP and JavaScript. I tried some ways to fix it and also asked ChatGPT to solve this problem, but the issue still persists.
Here is my code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>QR Code Scanner</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/html5-qrcode/minified/html5-qrcode.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #qr-reader {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            margin: auto;
        }
        #result {
            margin-top: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #camera-select {
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>QR Code Scanner</h1>
    <select id="camera-select"></select>
    <div id="qr-reader"></div>
    <div id="result">
        <p id="result-text">Scan a QR code to see the result here.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        async function initializeCameraSelection() {
            const cameraSelect = document.getElementById('camera-select');
            
            // Get available devices
            const devices = await Html5Qrcode.getCameras();
            if (devices && devices.length) {
                // Populate camera select options
                devices.forEach(device => {
                    const option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.value = device.id;
                    option.text = device.label || `Camera ${cameraSelect.options.length + 1}`;
                    cameraSelect.appendChild(option);
                });
                
                // Set default to first camera
                if (devices.length > 0) {
                    cameraSelect.value = devices[0].id;
                }
            } else {
                console.log("No cameras found.");
            }
        }

        async function startScanning() {
            const selectedCameraId = document.getElementById('camera-select').value;
            const html5QrCode = new Html5Qrcode("qr-reader");

            html5QrCode.start(
                { facingMode: { exact: selectedCameraId } }, // Select the chosen camera
                {
                    fps: 10,    // Frames per second
                    qrbox: 250  // QR box size
                },
                (decodedText, decodedResult) => {
                    document.getElementById('result-text').innerText = `QR Code content: ${decodedText}`;
                    console.log(`Scan result: ${decodedText}`);
                    // You can handle the scan result here (e.g., send it to the server or redirect)
                },
                (errorMessage) => {
                    console.log(`QR Code scan error: ${errorMessage}`);
                }
            ).catch(err => {
                console.log(`Error starting QR code scanner: ${err}`);
            });
        }

        // Initialize camera selection and start scanning
        initializeCameraSelection().then(() => {
            document.getElementById('camera-select').addEventListener('change', startScanning);
            startScanning(); // Start scanning with the default selected camera
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html> 

I tried everything that ChatGPT said, but the problem is still there, I'm expecting to show my camera in my browser to scan the QR code.

Have you checked the browser's Console for any errors?
